# Multilanguage bug

Tags: ios, swift, api, request

I have faced very strange bug in my application where I show list of news from remote server.

I have 2 languages - english as main, and russian as supplementary. My server has two json files, for eng and ru localisations. 
When requesting for data from server I do language check like this:

```
let preferredLanguage = NSLocale.preferredLanguages[0]

    if preferredLanguage == "uk" || preferredLanguage == "ru" {
        requestLink = RequestLinks.secondDateProgram.rawValue
    } else {
        requestLink = RequestLinksEng.secondDateProgram.rawValue
    }
```

And this all system works fine, correct link being generated and request shows correct data, all works fine but ONLY on my iPhone 7. 
When I install and launch exactly the same app version (from TestFlight or Diawi) on any other device my list of news in russian version of app for some reason has first item from english json file. But when I switch phone to english - everything works fine.

I don't have any cache, and I don't store any news to Realm. I do manual cache cleaning before each request and still the same - on my iPhone it works fine, on other nope(tested on iphone 7 plus, and 11).

If anyone had same issue before - would be grateful for any help.

Comment: First thing I'd do is look at server response and walk your way up through your data source etc. Make sure it all gets cleaned up and your fetched data looks what it should. It is really hard to give you some more insightful answer without knowing your code.

Comment: @Pancho Looking at logger found out that `let preferredLanguage = NSLocale.preferredLanguages[0]` is not working on release. It always shows that current phone language is english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was here - `let preferredLanguage = NSLocale.preferredLanguages[0]`
This detects **Application** language, but not **iPhone's**, that's why I got english instead of russian.

Changing it to `NSLocale.current.languageCode` did the trick.